# Where to test validation - in unit or functional test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, yii, tdd, validation

Where do you suggest to test validation?

This is a functional test from Yii demos:

```
// test login process, including validation
 $this->clickAndWait('link=Login');
 $this->assertElementPresent('name=LoginForm[username]');
 $this->type('name=LoginForm[username]','demo');
 $this->clickAndWait("//input[@value='Login']");
 $this->assertTextPresent('Password cannot be blank.');
```

But validation testing against each wrong case (such as "password is too long" or "email is incorrect") would take vaste amount of time. So, why not to test the validation only in unit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally provide one or two scenarios that show how the user sees the help for validation, but I usually phrase them at a higher level, for instance:

```
Given Fred forgets to fill in his phone and email
When he tries to register
Then he should be told what's missing.
```

Those steps can either be translated to a [simple code DSL](http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/source/browse/Example.PetShop.Scenarios/PetRegistrationAndPurchase.cs) or added to a tool like [Cucumber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucumber_(software)) (see [BDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bdd)). The validation scenarios (functional) are enough just to give an example of the capabilities of the system.

Examples of what is and isn't valid then go into unit tests, as you suggest.

If you think of functional scenarios as showcasing the capabilities of the system, and unit tests as showcasing the capabilities of the class or finer-grained element of code, it's easier to make the separation. Note that I've avoided the word "test" as a verb here, as even at a unit level it's still just examples.

Comment: Heh, whoops, thanks for the edit @bool-dev - yes, linking to the vegetable won't help too many software developers. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, It is your project and you can test what you want, where you want.

I usually test the entire validation in my model unit tests. After that, I also test it again (but less extensive) during my web tests (This is to test if the correct variables are being parsed by the controller, etc...)